# How Does WinHttpCrackurl Work

Tags: winhttp

The MSDN documentation on WinHttpCrackurl makes a point of saying it runs "synchronously".  But, could someone provide some authoritative documentation that says WinHttpCrackurl does or does not attempt a network connection?  I've searched fruitlessly and would like to avoid disassembling the function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WinHttpCrackUrl()` **DOES NOT** use the network in any way.  There is no documentation that states that, but all it does is parses the input string into its individual components, nothing more, so there is no need for the network.

Comment: thanks for the answer, though not what i was looking for, it will have to do

Comment: You are looking for something that does not exist. As I said, there is no documentation from Microsoft stating that `WinHttpCrackUrl()` does not use the network, even though it really doesn't.  The existing docs state that `WinHttpCrackUrl()` is synchronous only because WinHTTP can be used asynchronously and `WinHttpCrackUrl()` is always synchronous, nothing more.  That does not imply network usage.